# Get Quote and its author using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, random

I am very new to Swift, and I am trying to make an app of quotes, but I want to display the Quote and its own author both in a separate UILabel. But I don't know how to do this, because I have a randomQuote function that returns a random index for my array but the array only displays the quote, I want to get a random quote and get the author of the quote.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
   var quotes = ["'Stay Hungry, Stay Foolish.'", "'Life is what happens while you are busy making other plans.'", ""]

var authors = ["Steve Jobs", "John Lennon"]



func getRandomQuote() -> String{
    //get random index
    var arrayCount = UInt32(quotes.count)
    var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(arrayCount)
    var finalNumber = Int(randomNumber)

    return quotes[finalNumber]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var randomImage: String = imageChange[randomNumber]
    self.motivationText.text = getRandomQuote()
    self.imageInspire.image = UIImage(named: randomImage)
}
```

I was thinking about using a dictionary but I think it won't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your authors and quotes are always in the same order you can use the same finalNumber for both the quotes & author array.

You can set both labels inside of getRandomQuote and remove the String return, then you can call it from viewDidLoad.

A dictionary would work, you can treat it's keys as an array for random reasons and then just use the key/value pair to populate your labels.

Example if quotes & authors are always in the same order:

```
func getRandomQuote() {
//get random index
var arrayCount = UInt32(quotes.count)
var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(arrayCount)
var finalNumber = Int(randomNumber)

self.motivationText.text = quotes[finalNumber]
self.authorName.text = authors[finalNumber] // Just an assumption on label name

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getRandomQuote()

}
```

Dictionary example:

```
let quotesWithAuthors = ["Steve Jobs":"Stay Hungry, Stay Foolish","Alan Kay":"Simple things should be simple, complex things should be possible","Bill Gates":"I'm not fake Steve Jobs"]

let authorsArray = quotesWithAuthors.keys.array

let randomQuoteKeyIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(authorsArray.count - 1)))

self.authorName.text    = authorsArray[randomQuoteKeyIndex]
self.otivationText.text = quotesWithAuthors[authorsArray[randomQuoteKeyIndex]]
```

In essence they are very similar from an execution point of view but may be easier to store this way. Though you may run into problems if you have multiple quotes from the same author using an author name as a dictionary - in that case you may want to flip the author & quote.

Comment: Sorry but can you show me some code to understand please? haha

Comment: added one code example and adding another in a few moments.